# How do I get XCode capabilities when building with xcodebuild?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I use Background Mode (voip) capabilities for my app in XCode. When I build the app through XCode with a provisioning profile that is allowed this capability - the app works. But then I build my iOS app from command-line in the following manner:

```
xcodebuild -workspace test.xcworkspace -scheme test -sdk iphoneos clean build archive -archivePath test.xcarchive
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath test.xcarchive -exportPath acc exportFormat ipa
```

When building an ipa in this way and installing it on the iPhone the Background Mode voip isn't active in the app. How can I get the Background mode capability active when building through command-line with xcodebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the "xcodebuild -exportArchive ..." line was deprecated without using the -exportOptionsPlist argument. So I created an options.plist in the same directory that looked like:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>734KHEMHW2</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

With my corresponding team ID found on http://developer.apple.com.

Then used the following line to export to ipa:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist options.plist -archivePath test.xcarchive -exportPath .
```

And this successfully created the ipa with voip capabilities enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Executing xcodebuild is based on how you setup your project using Xcode. I am assuming here you've already done this.

Regarding background modes, you would also need to ensure that your Info.plist (or whatever you named it) contains UIBackgroundModes (this is the raw key) you want.

[image]

When you build via xcodebuild, all the proper info will get picked up, provided your project is setup properly.

More info on background execution is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Yes. My Info.plist contains:  <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>voip</string>
 </array>

Comment: Just for clarity, you also have run the same scheme from Xcode? And are you sure you are using the same provisioning file? Things like this require a bit of sleuthing. This usually involves first comparing the Xcode build output compared to the xcodebuild output. Your focus really would be on the tail end where linking/code signing/etc occur. If it looks the same, then compare the entitlements file and plist in each .app file.